# How to copy and paste the previous value to next empty cell in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, copy, paste

1. I have excel file

   ```
   |  Name   |   City    | Start Date | 
   |Alex     | Hong Kong | 2021-02-01 |
   |Annie    | Hong Kong |            |
   |Bob      | Taipei    |            | 
   |Lucy     | Tokyo     |            |
   |David    | London    | 2021-07-01 |
   |Kate     | New York  |            | 
   |Cathrine | London    |            | 
   |Rose     | Hong Kong |            | 
   |Mary     | Hong Kong | 2021-09-01 |
   |Johnny   | London    |            | 
   |Roy      | Taipei    |            |
   ```
2. I want to use python auto update the start date in empty cell like as below result.

   ```
   |  Name   |   City    | Start Date | 
   |Alex     | Hong Kong | 2021-02-01 |
   |Annie    | Hong Kong | 2021-02-01 |
   |Bob      | Taipei    | 2021-02-01 | 
   |Lucy     | Tokyo     | 2021-02-01 |
   |David    | London    | 2021-07-01 |
   |Kate     | New York  | 2021-07-01 | 
   |Cathrine | London    | 2021-07-01 | 
   |Rose     | Hong Kong | 2021-07-01 | 
   |Mary     | Hong Kong | 2021-09-01 |
   |Johnny   | London    | 2021-09-01 | 
   |Roy      | Taipei    | 2021-09-01 |
   ```
3. I use `openpyxl` read  excel file

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Data.xlsx')
   ```
4. How to copy and paste the previous start date value to next empty cell?

   ```
   col = df['Start Date'] = np.where(df['Start Date'].isnull())
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(df['Start Date']):
    if d.strip() == '':
        df.at[i,'Start Date'] = df.at[i-1,'Start Date']
```

Assuming your date fields are string. You probably have to adjust to your exact formatting.